# Would my IP be recorded when I visit a website

Tags: ip, anonymity, websites, web-hosting, domain

Could the website owner (admin) determine whether to record users IP?

If the website owner (admin) doesn’t want to record users IP, will the host provider or domain name provider still get and record users IP?

For example I buy a domain name (say, some website.eu) from namescheap.com, so namescheap company is the domain name provider. Then I will hire a host for that domain name, say, I hired it from HUAWEI cloud, then HUAWEI cloud is the host provider. And I am the website owner (admin).

Comment: CN you clarify what you mean by host provider and domain name provider?

Comment: @ConorMancone I’ve made an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website admin certainly knows your IP Address. If they didn't they couldn't send you the website you requested. Whether or not they record your address or try to track you is entirely up to them.

The same applies for the hosting provider as well as everyone between them and you, starting with your ISP.

The domain name registrar doesn't know anything about who visits the domain. However, the DNS server does. Sometimes the registrar will also host your DNS, so they might find out information about who visits the site. However this is probably very rare in practice because normally they wouldn't handle DNS requests directly from users. DNS is a distributed system, so usually the DNS host just talks to other DNS servers that are making requests for users and don't pass along end-user information.